# Android Lollipop - Colour Inversion API

Tags: android, accessibility, android-5.0-lollipop

I note that Lollipop has a new feature under accessibility to enable/disable colour inversion. Is there an API for accessing this functionality programatically?

Any help appreciated

Comment: No, there is no API.

Comment: Curious, why would you want to know this? What would you do with this information?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do now is to open the accessibility page where the option is:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS));
```